# Android list all ftp folders and subfolders

Tags: java, android, recursion

I am trying to list all folders and subfolders in my ftp account in recursion.
The function ftpPrintDirsList returns Array List of folders in the folder.
If i have this folders:
a/b/c, a/b/d/e, a/f/g/, a/f/g/h, a/f/g/i

I need to get Array List that looks like this: a, a/b, a/b/c, a/b/d, a/b/d/e, a/f, a/f/g, a/f/g/h, a/f/g/i
(The order does not have to be that way, but i need to see all the folders)

So far i got stuck here:

```
    ArrayList<String> fassD = ftpPrintDirsList("/FlashAssets");
    ArrayList<String> inner = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < fassD.size(); i++) //for each subfolder in FlashAssets
    {
        inner = ftpPrintDirsList("/FlashAssets/"+fassD.get(i)); //list all subfolders

            for (int j = 0; j < inner.size(); j++) 
            {
            inner.set(j, fassD.get(i)+"/"+inner.get(j));
            fassD.addAll(inner);
            }

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Final: "+fassD);
```

But i get an infinite loop, can anyone help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say you're using recursion, is this code inside the ftpPrintDirsList method?

Comment: Actually no, this is the whole code. By recursion i meant that i add all folders to fassD and then the loop goes again with the new folders

Comment: but you are adding inner.size times inner to fassD

Comment: and you need to iterate o to make a recursion otherwise you will get only the first two levels

Comment: to get final Array List that contains all folders

Comment: but you need to do fassD.addAll(inner); only once per each inner array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive method, assuming that ftpPrintDirsList does what it describes.  For each folder, it adds itself to the list, then calls the method for all subfolders.  When there are no subfolders, it will add itself to the list then return.  This will give you a depth first ordering of your files.  /a/b/c comes before a/c

```
public ArrayList<String> getFolders(String foldername)
{
  ArrayList<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();
  retval.add(foldername);
  ArrayList<String> subfolders = ftpPrintDirsList(foldername);
  for (String folder : subfolders)
    retval.addall(getFolders(foldername + folder));
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, added little fix: foldername +"/"+ folder.